# Remove white space between QTableView cell and QWidget inside cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qgroupbox

I have a `QGroupBox` inside a `QTableView` cell. The `QGroupBox` consists of a `QHBoxLayout` which contains two `QRadioButton`s.

I have tried setContentsMargins on the layout and the groupbox but there seems to always be a margin/white space on the top.

[image]

```
QGroupBox *widget = new QGroupBox();
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
QRadioButton *wsRadioButton_ = new QRadioButton( this );
QRadioButton *pfRadioButton_ = new QRadioButton( this );
widget->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
layout->setContentsMargins( 10, 0, 0, 0 );
layout->addWidget(pfRadioButton_, Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->addWidget(wsRadioButton_, Qt::AlignCenter);
widget->setLayout(layout);
ui_->fsTableView_->setIndexWidget( model_->index( eModelRows::eRS, eModelCols::min ), widget );
ui_->fsTableView_->resizeRowToContents( eModelRows::eRS );
```

Comment: Remove the group box and replace it by a plain widget. Group boxes are for showing a label in the top area.. and it reserves space for that label, presumably.

Comment: Change `QGroupBox *widget = new QGroupBox();` to  `QWidget *widget = new QWidget();`

Comment: Thank you @JohannesSchaub-litb and eyllanesc. That did it. If you could put it in an answer I can mark it as accepted.